# Prove that there is exactly one homomorphism $\varphi\colon G \rightarrow H$ for which $\varphi (g)=h$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, with $G=\langle g \rangle$ an infinite cyclic group, and let $h \in H.$ Prove that there is exactly one homomorphism $\varphi\colon G \rightarrow H$ for which $\varphi (g)=h.$

I know that a homomorphism is a function $\varphi\colon G \rightarrow H$ such that $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y).$
I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the conditions given to deduce the statement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uniqueness:** Assume $\phi,\psi$ are two such homomorphisms. Let $x\in G$. Then there exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=g^k$ and we have $$\phi(x)=\phi(g^k)=\phi(g)^k=h^k=\phi(g)^k=\psi(g^k)=\psi(x). $$

**Existence:** Given $x\in G$, there exists a unique $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=g^k$. Set $\phi(x)=h^k$. To verify that this is a homomoerphism, note  that for $x,y\in G$, $x=g^k$, $y=g^\ell$, say, we have $$\phi(xy)=\phi(g^kg^\ell)=\phi(g^{k+\ell})=h^{k+\ell}=h^kh^{\ell}=\phi(x)\phi(y). $$
And of course the desired condition $ \phi(g)=\phi(g^1)=h^1=h$ holds as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k\in G$, i.e. there is a $n$ s.t. $k=g^n$. Let $\varphi,\psi$ two homomorphism from $G\to H$ s.t. $\varphi(g)=\psi(g)=h$. Then,

$$(\varphi-\psi)(k)=(\varphi-\psi)(g^n)=\varphi(g)^n-\psi(g)^n=h^n-h^n=0.$$
Therefore, $\varphi=\psi$. For the existence, just prove that $k\longmapsto h^k$ is an homomorphism.